# Switch Fabric onboarding from Xcode to CocoaPods (*.xcodeproj to *.xcworkspace)

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, google-fabric

I recently switched to using CocoaPods for managing dependencies in my iOS apps. So I'm going through all my apps, deleting the frameworks and adding them again via CocoaPods.

I deleted the Fabric and Crashlytics frameworks, added the pods:

- `pod 'Fabric'`
- `pod 'Crashlytics'`

and ran `pod install`.

I also changed the run script from

```
./Crashlytics.framework/run [yourAPIKey]
```

to

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run" [yourAPIKey]`
```

Everything works as expected, and the app works perfectly fine, except one thing. On the Fabric mac app, with the app selected, if I try to update Crashlytics by clicking Crashlytics > Update, it tries to open the *.xcodeproj file instead of the new *.xcworkspace file I'm now using with CocoaPods.

If I already have the *.xcworkspace file open, and click 'Update' in the Fabric app, it will attempt to open the *.xcodeproj file and Xcode will complain:

> Cannot open "[app_name].xcodeproj" because it is already open in another workspace.

If Fabric is installed into a new project via CocoaPods, it will always open the correct file (*.xcworkspace). How do I tell the Fabric app to open an app's *.xcworkspace file instead of the old *.xcodeproj file?

**I don't want to delete the app from Fabric and re-add it, because I will lose all the old data.**

Comment: Why are you using the Mac app to update the frameworks anyway? That's now cocoapod's job - run `pod update` if you want to update.

Comment: @Gereon you're right, I thought about that then, but I'll leave it here for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the Fabric mac app, add a new app by clicking *'+ New App'*
2. Click on the **.xcworkspace** file of the app. *Note: This will **not** add a new duplicate app, but will overwrite the configuration of the existing app while leaving all the history and past versions of the app intact.)*
3. Follow the steps in the Fabric app for onboarding. **Make sure you choose the Podfile onboarding method to install via CocoaPods.**